# Battery level indicator

Tags: arduino-uno

In this arduino project we have 3 Leds that lights up according to the voltage of a battery but when we the voltage read is very close, it results into an uncontrolled switching between  Leds  can any one help me ?

```
int Batpin = A0;
int Led1  = 12;    
int Led2  = 11;    
int Led3 = 10;    

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin (9600);      
  pinMode(Led1,OUTPUT);     
  pinMode(Led2,OUTPUT);      
  pinMode(Led3,OUTPUT);    

}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  volt ();
}

void volt(){      
int sensorVal = analogRead(Batpin);      
float voltage = sensorVal * (5.0/1023.0);     

 Serial.print(" volt: ");    
 Serial.println(voltage);    
 if (voltage < 3.80){        
     digitalWrite(Led1,HIGH);        
  }      

   if (voltage > 3.80 && voltage <= 4)
   {     
      digitalWrite(Led1,LOW);      
      digitalWrite(Led2,HIGH);
   }

   if (voltage > 4)
   {
      digitalWrite(Led1,LOW);
      digitalWrite(Led2,LOW);
      digitalWrite(Led3,HIGH);
   }     
   delay (1000);
}
```

Comment: This is an interesting project.  But why stop at adding hysteresis?  After all, you have the flexibility of a micro processor.  Start thinking "out of the box" and make a more useful tool.  What about the battery's internal resistance, its elasticity and how that effects its performance?

Comment: You can reduce this effect a bit by using the average of multiple reads. This will give you a more stable value and less hysteresis. You could for example use a rolling average. To absolutely eliminate this proble use majenko's solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you could do with for this is *[hysteresis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hysteresis)*.

Instead of simple threshold ranges (0 < A < B < C < 5) you instead need to watch the voltage over time and decide what it is doing compared with what it has done in the past.

You need to keep a record of what state the voltage is in at any one time - That is, is it in band A, B or C in the thresholds above. You then need a second set of thresholds, A1, B1 and C1.

The two thresholds overlap:

[image]

If, for example, the voltage rises from between A and B to between B1 and C1 then you switch states to the BC state.

If it falls from between B1 and C1 to between A and B then you switch to the AB state.

Basically, if the voltage rises, it needs to transition between the lower set of thresholds to the upper set of thresholds to register as a change. If it drops it has to transition between the upper set of thresholds and the lower set of thresholds to register as a change.

So, in pseudocode,

```
if (State == 0A && Voltage > A1 && Voltage < B1)
    State = AB
    Turn on LED 1

if (State == AB && Voltage > B1 && Voltage < C1)
    State = BC
    Turn on LED 2

if (State == BC && Voltage > C1)
    State = C5
    Turn on LED 3

if (State == BC && Voltage < B && Voltage > A) 
    State = AB
    Turn on LED 2

if (State == AB && Voltage < A) 
    State = 0A
    Turn on LED 1

if (State == C5 && Voltage < C && Voltage > B) 
    State = BC
    Turn off all LEDs
```

It's up to you to decide what a good level of separation is suitable for your system.